# Removing selected row from an array using splice in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue in removing the particular item from an array.I have tried using splice but, the last row is removing instead of the particular row.I am providing the plunker link here :

```
   $scope.rows.splice($index, 1);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/WETSLqOXlTwiHq4p9IUt?p=preview
Any help would be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Just responded to your comment on my solution. The way I did it makes it super easy to access the text too (as long as you know what row you want to get the text of - see my comment for details). Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
just try the following
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oymo9g2f/2/

```
you have some problem with your array splice
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this code. For text area used `ng-model="row.value"` and related change in controller

in html: just shown `ng-repeat` part

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">             
     <div class="col s12 m4" >
        <label for="destination_features1" >Features</label>
        <textarea  id="destination_features1" name="destination_features1_{{$index}}" ng-model="row.value" placeholder="Data Here"  type="text" ></textarea>                        
     </div>
     <button ng-show="show_removebtn" id="removeButton"  ng-click="removeDynamically($index)" type="button">Remove</button>                             
</div>
```

and in controller:

```
  $scope.rows = []; 
  $scope.current_rows = 0;
  $scope.destination_details = {};
  $scope.rows.push({
    row_num: $scope.current_rows,
    value: ''
  });

  $scope.addDynamically = function() {
    $scope.current_rows += 1;
    $scope.rows.push({
      row_num: $scope.current_rows,
      value: ''
    });

    if ($scope.rows.length > 1) {
      $scope.show_removebtn = true;
    }
  };


  $scope.removeDynamically = function(index) {
    if (index > -1) {
      $scope.rows.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish (as your code looks like you are quite new to AngularJS, but I created a different (but similar) implementation that should fit your needs (it's easier to read IMHO and is scalable):

HTML:

```
<div class="card ">        
        <form name="add_destination_form" class="col s12" ng-submit="add_destination_form.$valid && addDestination_Details(destination_details)" novalidate>
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">             
                <div class="col s12 m4" >
                    <label for="destination_features1" >Features</label>
                    <textarea  id="destination_features1" name="destination_features1_{{$index}}" ng-model="destination_details.destination_features1[$index]" placeholder="Data Here"  type="text" ></textarea>                        
                </div>
                <button ng-show="show_removebtn" id="removeButton"  ng-click="removeDynamically($index)" type="button">Remove</button>                              
            </div> 

            <div class="col s12 m4">                 
                <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" ng-click="addDynamically()" type="button">Add More</button>                                
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col s12 m4">
                    <button  type="submit">Submit</button>                              
                </div>

            </div>  
        </form>           
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.rows = [{
  "row_num": 0,
  "text": ""
}];

$scope.addDynamically = function (index) {
   console.log(index);
    $scope.rows.push({
        "row_num": index,
        "text": ""
    });
};

$scope.removeDynamically = function (index) {
  $scope.rows.splice(index, 1);
};
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CGqgaxMGPbH70Yc1m2ZL?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your help,But the problem with this is,when i use row.text then how should i get the data of the text fields into controller

Comment: @ShaikNizamuddin If you want to access, say, the first row's text all you have to do is something like `var firstRowsText = $scope.rows[0].text` :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add line:

```
$scope.destination_details = {"destination_features1": ['1']};
```

at the beginning.

Also need to remove model properly when removing element:

```
$scope.destination_details.destination_features1.splice($index, 1);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/pe44Moqe7ymegYFTrXJu?p=preview

Comment: When i do this I am getting an error $scope.destination_details.destination_features1.splice is not a function and the last row is removing.

Comment: I don't see this error im my example - it is working properly. Where you get this error?

Comment: Are you init first list element model by value $scope.destination_details = {"destination_features1": ['']};  ?

Comment: The error is in your code the "$scope.destination_details.destination_features1" data is in array,but in my code the data is in array of object.

Comment: yes i did.In my array i am getting values with keys as ["0":1,"1":2]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. I gave you a working example where the element model initialized with initial value and properly updated. You use "destination_details.destination_features1[$index]" as a model, so destination_details.destination_features1 is an array of models - each element of it need to be updated when you remove an element. You need to splice an element from this array.

Comment: You can not use {"0":1,"1":2} because all indexes changed when you removing element. You need [1, 2] instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152019/discussion-between-shaik-nizamuddin-and-alexander-bolzhatov).